# Pupeteer - Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: TABLE_ROW_SELECTOR is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, puppeteer

[image]

I'm getting started with pupeteer and node and using vscode. I'm trying to log into a site and scrape a table. So far I have:

```
(async () => {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
});
var page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('thesite.com/login/');

await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);

await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);

await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
await page.waitForNavigation();

const TABLE_ROW_SELECTOR = '.gv-container.gv-container-133 > table > tbody';
await page.waitForSelector(TABLE_ROW_SELECTOR);

await page.waitForSelector(TABLE_ROW_SELECTOR);


await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });  
const data = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(TABLE_ROW_SELECTOR));




await browser.close();
})();
```

This is mostly working. the script appears to execute down to :

```
const data = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll(TABLE_ROW_SELECTOR));
```

where it gives the error in the title. The screenshot is above does not show the table which is below the location of the screenshot. When I enter

```
document.querySelectorAll(TABLE_ROW_SELECTOR));
```

into the devtools console I get the expected html. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

in my console I see a list of objects but as far as I can tell no values. Heres the fiest object

```
0:Object {}
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
__defineGetter__:function __defineGetter__() { … }
__defineSetter__:function __defineSetter__() { … }
__lookupGetter__:function __lookupGetter__() { … }
__lookupSetter__:function __lookupSetter__() { … }
constructor:function Object() { … }
hasOwnProperty:function hasOwnProperty() { … }
No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'
isPrototypeOf:function isPrototypeOf() { … }
No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'
```

What does "    No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function argument of `page.evaluate()` is executed in the document (browser) context and has no access to the variables of the Node.js script. You need to transfer these variables by values:

```js
const data = await page.evaluate(SELECTOR => document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR), TABLE_ROW_SELECTOR);
```

Comment: Thanks that gets rid of the error, however please see edit above..

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be vscode issue, I do not use it. It is better to ask a new question about it, maybe with vscode in title and tags.